# How to count decimal digits of an integer?

Tags: c++, numbers, cmath

I wrote a program to determine the number of digits in a number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long num1 = 1999999999999999;
    long long num2 = 9999999999999999;
    int number_of_digit_1 = log10(num1) + 1;
    int number_of_digit_2 = log10(num2) + 1;
    cout << number_of_digit_1 << endl;
    cout << number_of_digit_2 << endl;
}
```

The output is this

```
16 
17
```

Eventhough it shoudld print the same number (16). Why does this happen?

Comment: When you call `log10`, `num2`is first converted to a `double`, with less precision.

Comment: see what happened if number_of_digit_1  and 2 are doubles and not ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`log10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10) takes various floating point types as arguments and returns the same type in its result. In your case it is converting to `double`.

`double` only has `53` bits for it's integer (significand) part.

`9999999999999999` needs 54 bits to be represented accurately.

When you convert `9999999999999999` to `double` you get `10000000000000000` so the result of `16` from `log10(9999999999999999)` is to be expected.

To get an accurate (and probably faster) count of digits in an integer you should use an integer method for calculating the digits. There are various techniques for example [What is the fastest method of calculating integer Log10 for 64-bit integers on modern x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032982/what-is-the-fastest-method-of-calculating-integer-log10-for-64-bit-integers-on-m) or http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog

Comment: Actually I got 17 when using log10(9999999999999999), not 16. But great explanation by the way

Comment: `log10(9999999999999999)` returns `16`, you add 1 to get `17`

Answer (score 0):

`log10(long long int)` is not defined. Then, `num2` is implicitly converted to a `double`, which has less precision. Converting `num2` to a `long double` solves the problem.

This workaround does not work with visual studio (there, double = long double). However, it works with gcc and clang.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long num1 = 1999999999999999;
    long long num2 = 9999999999999999;
    long double x = static_cast<long double> (num2);
    int number_of_digit_1 = log10(num1) + 1;
    int number_of_digit_2 = log10(num2) + 1;
    int number_of_digit_3 = log10(x) + 1;
    cout << number_of_digit_1 << endl;
    cout << number_of_digit_2 << endl;
    cout << number_of_digit_3 << endl;
}
```

Another possibility is to use a simple dedicated function to calculate the number of digits, with a simple `while`loop. Generally, a high efficiency is not the concern in such a situation.

```
template <typename T> 
int n_digits (T num) {
    int n = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        ++n;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: This assumes `long double` is large enough to accurately hold `num2`, on visual studio it [isn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I didn't know for visual studio, not using it. I *only* tested it with gcc and clang. Edited the post

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for editing the post, but has everyone access to the edit history?

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged/255685#255685, everyone can click on the `edited x minutes ago` link to see the edit history